# How to find and plot Implied volatility in R

Tags: r

I'm writing because I want to find and plot implied volatility to the BS model using R. However, I'm not used to coding in R and I honestly don't know where to start so I wanted to ask if anyone on this forum has written such a code in R and therefor maybe could bed able to help me?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I see I may have offended a few people by simply asking for code. I apologize for that. All I perhaps need to ask is where people on this forum usually get financial data to use in R from?

- Mads

Comment: Welcome to SO - questions asking for help with a problem in code you have attempted are better received than questions just asking for code and not showing any attempt.

Comment: You may want to read **whathaveyoutried.com** & show some respect to the StackOverflow Community, which strongly encourages to post high quality questions, altogether with a MCVE ( **a Minimum-Complete-Verifiable-Example of code** ) showing what-you-have-tried so far. You may want to update your post, so as to meet this minimum reasonable level of quality & to show your will to respect other StackOverflow contributing members. They are professionals who love to answer good questions on MCVE-related issues. **Enjoy being StackOverflow Contributing Member & do support this Community Netiquette**

Comment: Hi!

Thanks for the comment. I see what you're getting at. Maybe I don't need direct help with the code, but more with how to load the market data in to R. I'm completely clueless as of where to start, but I was thinking that I wanted data on the S&P500 and compute the implied volatility from there. Do you know where to get data compatible with R?

- Mads

Comment: Mads, have done some elementary research on this? May want to step forwards with >>> http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2012/10/25/

Comment: S&P500? Black-Scholes model deals with **pricing of Options**.

Comment: Yes, but you use a underlying e.g. a stock :)

Comment: Have a look at the [CRAN Task View for Empirical Finance](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Finance.html) which lists several relevant packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Posted by: Renato Vitolo
           Quantitative risk analyst at Banca Monte dei Paschi di Siena
```

Error handling is not stupendous, I ought to admit, but it's past bedtime. Try this from an R terminal:

> **source**(url("http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rv211/BS/BS-Newton.R"))

**Example 1**: data taken from http://www.maxi-pedia.com/Black+Scholes+model

**Example 2**: data taken from http://voices.yahoo.com/the-black-scholes-formula-practice-problems-solutions-1297845.html?cat=4

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to see if I can apply some of this to market data on my own. I'm really a newbie when it comes to coding so I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MadsChristensen - were you able to achieve this? I'd be interested to know how you solved this problem. Thanks